# ReactJS Call a function in render after an action

Tags: reactjs, polaris

I'm using ReactJS, and shopify's polaris in order to create a website. I'm very new to react so this might be a newbie question but I looked over the internet and couldn't manage to put the pieces together.

I have a dropdown list and basically whenever the user clicks on an item from a list I want to add a button next to the dropdown. Here is my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { ActionList, Button, List, Popover } from "@shopify/polaris";

export default class ActionListExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: false,
      title: "Set Period",
    };
  }

renderButton() {
    console.log("Button clicked")
    return (
      <div>
        <Button fullWidth={true}>Add product</Button>;
      </div>
    );
 }

togglePopover = () => {
this.setState(({ active }) => {
  return { active: !active };
});
};

render() {
  const activator = (
    <Button onClick={this.togglePopover}>{this.state.title}</Button>
  );
return (
  <div style={{ height: "250px" }}>
    <Popover
      active={this.state.active}
      activator={activator}
      onClose={this.togglePopover}
    >
      <ActionList
        items={[
          {
            content: "One",
            onAction: () => {
              this.setState({ title: "One" }, function() {
                this.togglePopover();
                this.renderButton() //THIS IS WHERE I CALL THE METHOD
              });
            }
          }
        ]}
      />
    </Popover>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

I've placed a comment in the code to show where I call the renderButton() method. Whenever I click the "One" element in the dropdown, it prints out "Button clicked" but nothing gets rendered to the screen. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `{this.state.active && this.renderButton()}` <-- put that where you want the button to render.

Comment: @azium I did that and I still get the same behaviour

Comment: can you show us your code when you have that? I'm very skeptical that you tried exactly what i'm suggesting

Comment: ah didn't notice popup was also using `active`. @izb has the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another variable to check if an item is clicked, and as @azium commented, you need to add the output to your JSX, not inside the `onAction` function.

As of right now, you close the `Popper` when an item is clicked, setting `this.state.active` to `false`, so you can't rely on that to render your button. You need to add something like `this.state.isButton` or something and in `onAction` include:

```
onAction: () => {
  this.setState({ title: "One", isButton: true }, () => {
    this.togglePopover();
   });
}
```

and then in your JSX:

```
{this.state.isButton && this.renderButton()}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).
You basically want to render a component based on a condition (Boolean from your state in this case).

Conditional rendering can be written is several ways [as you can see in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator).

In your case i would go for something like this:

```
return (
  <div style={{ height: "250px" }}>
    <Popover
      active={this.state.active}
      activator={activator}
      onClose={this.togglePopover}
    >
      <ActionList
        items={[
          {
            content: "One",
            onAction: () => {
              this.setState({ title: "One" }, function() {
                this.togglePopover();
              });
            }
          }
        ]}
      />
      {this.state.active && this.renderButton()}
    </Popover>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

Note that i just placed it at a random place, feel free to move it wherever you need it in the markup.

Comment: Hello @Sagiv b.g. Doing what you suggested created a button in the dropdown list. I wanted a button to appear next to the dropdown whenever I clicked on the item in the dropdown list.

Comment: So when `this.state.active` is not an indicator you clicked the item?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that but I posted a solution here that finally worked. I combined everyones idea. It was basically what you did except I added a isButton in the state.

Comment: this is exactly what i meant, in your case `isButton` is the indicator (the condition) to whether or not render the component. the important part is **How** you render conditionally (which i showed you in my answer and provided the links to the docs), the condition itself is depended on your logic.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to everyone's help I finally was able to do this. I placed an extra attribute in the state called isButton and I initially set it equal to false. Here is my render function:

```
render() {
 const activator = (
   <Button onClick={this.togglePopover}>{this.state.title}</Button>
 );
return (
  <div style={{ height: "250px" }}>
    <Popover
      active={this.state.active}
      activator={activator}
      onClose={this.togglePopover}
    >
      <ActionList
        items={[
        {
        content: "One",
        onAction: () => {
          this.setState({ title: "One", isButton: true }, function() { //Set isButton to true
            this.togglePopover();
          });
        }
      }
    ]}
  />
{this.state.isButton && this.renderButton()} //ADDED HERE
</Popover>
  </div>
);
}
```

Please look at the comments to see where code was changed. Thanks!

Comment: the other answers / comments covered this